# sklearn FunctionTransfromer with imported functions

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to put data processing pipeline together.  One of the steps requires applying numpy.stats.boxcox with a specific lmbda value on a feature.  I think I should use the FunctionTransformer for this.  I can get it to work for a basic function that doesn't have any parameters, but I cannot get it to work for the boxcox function with a specific lambda.  I think I'm not passing in arguments correctly (see below):

I can get FunctionTransformer to work on a basic function:

```
def plus_one(X):
    return X + 1

b = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], np.int32)

plus = FunctionTransformer(plus_one)

x = plus.transform(b)

print('b')
print(b)

print('')
print('b+1')
print(b + 1)

print('')
print('b + 1 by transformer')
print(x)
```

Output is:

```
b
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]

b+1
[[2 3 4]
 [5 6 7]]

b + 1 by transformer
[[2 3 4]
 [5 6 7]]
```

I cannot get it to work on a more complicated function like boxcox:

```
from scipy import stats

print('boxcox(b)')
print(stats.boxcox(b, lmbda = 0.21411476060664147))


bc_trans = FunctionTransformer(stats.boxcox(lmbda = 0.21411476060664147))
y = bc_trans.transform(b)

print('')
print('boxcox(b) by transformation')
```

Output is:

```
boxcox(b)
[[0.         0.7472251  1.23858159]
 [1.61400018 1.92154649 2.18396975]]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-111-3615afca78ec> in <module>()
      5 
      6 
----> 7 bc_trans = FunctionTransformer(stats.boxcox(lmbda = 0.21411476060664147))
      8 y = bc_trans.transform(b)
      9 

TypeError: boxcox() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a function (like the `plus_one` from your example) that wraps the `boxcox` call. Secondly you need to pass the function definition and not the function call. This codes solve your issues:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
from scipy import stats


def bx(X):
    return stats.boxcox(X, lmbda=0.21411476060664147)

b = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], np.int32)

bc_trans = FunctionTransformer(bx)
y = bc_trans.transform(b)

print('')
print('boxcox(b) by transformation')
```

Notice that the code above defines a function `bx` and passes the function (not a function call) to the `FunctionTransformer`. A more **pythonic** solution would be to use partial. Just add

```
from functools import partial
```

to your imports and change the function definition by this:

```
bx = partial(stats.boxcox, lmbda=0.21411476060664147)
```